# Permanent redirect of subdomains to www. in lighttpd?

Tags: redirect, subdomain, lighttpd

I want to redirect all subdomain paths on domainxyz.com to www.domainxyz.com except for cdn.domainxyz.com and ad.domainxyz.com.

To clarify: I want for example abc.domainxyz.com/cat.php?id=23 redirect to www.domainxyz.com/cat.php?id=23.

How do I do this in lighttpd?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
# load mod_redirect
server.modules += ("mod_redirect")

# redirect everything to www. (with exceptions)
$HTTP["host"] =~ "^(.*\.)*domainxyz\.com$" {
    $HTTP["host"] !~ "^(ad|cdn|www)\.domainxyz\.com$" {
        url.redirect = ( "^/(.*)" => "http://www.domainxyz.com/$1" )
    }
}

# main vhost entry
$HTTP["host"] == "www.domainxyz.com" {
    server.document-root = "/var/www/domainxyz.com/"
}
```

More info on the official wiki: http://redmine.lighttpd.net/wiki/lighttpd/Docs:ModRedirect